# Flash drive completely disappeared after format on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: usb, 22.04, disk

I tried to format Flash Drive via Disks and set Erase option, after some time Disks got an error about formatting drive, I closed it and tried once more. Then after some time I got error again and Flash Drive disappeared from Disks. I tried to find it via gparts, disks, BIOS and it wasn't there.
Before formatting my flash drive was named sdc, now when running `sudo lsblk`, I get only sda(HDD) and sdb(SSD with system on it):

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0    7:0    0 302.6M  1 loop /snap/code/147
loop1    7:1    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop2    7:2    0 105.8M  1 loop /snap/core/16202
loop3    7:3    0  55.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/2812
loop4    7:4    0  63.4M  1 loop /snap/core20/1974
loop5    7:5    0  74.1M  1 loop /snap/core22/1033
loop6    7:6    0  73.9M  1 loop /snap/core22/858
loop7    7:7    0 514.8M  1 loop /snap/gimp/412
loop8    7:8    0 349.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143
loop9    7:9    0 485.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/120
loop10   7:10   0   497M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/141
loop11   7:11   0   140K  1 loop /snap/gtk2-common-themes/13
loop12   7:12   0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop13   7:13   0 571.7M  1 loop /snap/obs-studio/1294
loop14   7:14   0 642.1M  1 loop /snap/pycharm-community/357
loop15   7:15   0 642.2M  1 loop /snap/pycharm-community/358
loop16   7:16   0  12.3M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/959
loop17   7:17   0  53.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19457
loop18   7:18   0  40.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/20290
loop19   7:19   0   452K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/83
loop20   7:20   0 414.1M  1 loop /snap/telegram-desktop/5305
loop21   7:21   0 321.1M  1 loop /snap/vlc/3721
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
sdb      8:16   0 447.1G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0     1M  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0   513M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sdb3   8:19   0 446.6G  0 part /
```

The only way I can look if PC sees drive, running `sudo lsusb` :

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 1e3d:198a Chipsbank Microelectronics Co., Ltd Flash Disk
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:8771 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0951:170b Kingston Technology HyperX Cloud Stinger Core Wireless + 7.1
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 046d:c092 Logitech, Inc. G203 LIGHTSYNC Gaming Mouse
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c328 Logitech, Inc. Corded Keyboard K280e
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Flash Disk disappears after I unplug it.
Is there a way to get back control over my Flash Drive? I am mostly concerned about it being hidden from BIOS, but still seen in USBs.

Comment: Likely a flash drive that is ready for recycling.